# Unable to get video from my Samsung laptop's VGA port to display on my projector

Tags: laptop, vga, projector

I have SAMSUNG RV511 laptop, and it's VGA port seems to not pass video to the projector.

When I use different laptop with same cable and same projector it works fine, note that the graphic card seems to work okay.

I was told that I need to buy a new motherboard, but it will cost me a lot. Is there any other option?

For example:

- A cable that convert from USB to VGA?
- or HDMI to VGA?

What is the best solution, and how can I know if the product is compatible with my SAMSUNG?

Comment: Did you take a look in the display options? Sometimes, newly connected displays are not activated automatically. Alternatively, you can use the Win-P shortcut to quickly select the desired screen configuration. It's output, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel, I have used Win - P doesn't work I see blue screen on the projector, as I have said in the post same conditions with different laptop works okay.
The VGA output seems to be damaged.

Comment: Does any body of you use these cables and suggest any helpful info?

Comment: What kind of connector is on your projector? Are you using VGA to VGA?

Comment: Just one last question to verify – have you tested your notebook with other VGA displays/projectors?